# How do I parse this wrongly encoded Unicode data (Java)?

Tags: java, unicode

I have to parse output from a system I have no control over using Java. It outputs XML files containing nodes similar to:

```xml
<text>
Sample data
On multiple lines</text>
```

However, sometimes the data contains Unicode symbols such as a [RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm) `’` which is output as such (surrounded by normal text):

```xml
<text>â&#128;&#153;</text>
```

Using a hex editor the bytes in the file for the â are `C3A2`. Expected result is "’".

For a  emoji I receive:

```xml
<text>ð&#159;&#146;¯</text>
```

The bytes for ð are `C3B0` and for ¯ are `C2AF`. Expected result is "".

I can easily replace the escaped characters with the corresponding bytes e.g. `80` and `99`, but is it possible to detect the other erroneous characters, the length of the affected section and replace it with the correct Unicode character?

Edit: Another fuller example

```xml
<text>Weâ&#128;&#153;re ð&#159;&#146;¯ going to win</text>
```

Expected output: "We’re  going to win"

Comment: So the "standard-conforming" answer is: XML can handle Unicode, if you parse it conformantly and don't get the expected test, then the producer needs to fix their code. That might not actually be possible for you. Does the XML file have an encoding specified in the header? C3 B0 for ð suggests that you're parsing it as UTF-8.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yep, the XML is declared as UTF-8 and you're right that I have no way of changing the producer.

Answer (score 4):

The proper solution is to get the owners of the system that outputs this rubbish to correct it.

If that's really not possible, you might have a chance of correcting some the output some of the time.

Looking at how the output has been corrupted, taking the first example:

- `"’"` is "\u2019"
- `"\u2019".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` gives E2, 80, 99 in hex.
- The producer outputs these bytes as`â`, `&#128;` and `&#153;` respectively.
- You save those these bytes into a file and look at them using a hex editor. DON'T!

The problem with the last step is that you've also, yourself, created an additional artifact. You've saved the single byte 'â' using UTF-8 encoding, hence you get CA 32 which is not useful. Don't do that, as it complicates things further. The 'â' is readable as a single Java character with code '\u00E2'.

So what you need to do now is put those bytes together into a byte array. Save the 'â' into a single byte 0xE2. Take the `"&#128;"` and read 128 as a decimal value (equal to 80 hex), storing it in the next byte. Do the same with the third byte. Then decode the byte array back to a String:

`new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`

And you'll get your right single quotation mark as a single Java char.

Comment: Good analysis! It sounds like whatever produced the XML treated UTF-8 encoded data as having some other encoding and pushing it into some XML-producing tool without much verification (which then quoted whatever it thought it needed to). And just for the record: there is no standard-confirming way that this actually makes sense: this is obviously wrong output, no matter what the specified encoding of the file is.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Oh, totally. I have no chance of getting it fixed at source in a reasonable timescale because it's a data source from outside the company.

Comment: @k314159 Thanks, that makes sense. However I was looking at the original file with the hex editor and the â really is `C3A2` in the source. There's probably a previous process somewhere along the pipeline that does exactly what you described. I need a way of getting that `C3A2` back to `E2`.

Comment: @Steve Ah, that puts another spanner in the works!

Comment: Classic double-UTF-8 with some numeric XML entities thrown in for good measure. Delicious! I don't envy for having to build the mess that tries to decode that, but I have one suggestion: try to be *very particular* about what input you accept and error out whenever something doesn't follow one of the known "silly patterns". This way you can quickly react and fix your process whenever they inevitably mess up in some new and exciting way (or even when they miraculously start sending valid content at some point).

Comment: I think you might be able to decode UTF-8 twice, as it seems it was encoded to UTF-8 and then the resulting UTF-8 was again encoded to UTF-8.

Comment: Better still I wouldn't be surprised at all if this is only a problem in this single XML field and only in certain circumstances. My current idea is to strip out that part of the file and parse it separately as Windows-1252 then squirt the real text back into the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

To repair corrupt data might not catch all errors. The hack:

1. Read the file as Windows-1252. To fill in the entities `&...;` one must read it as XML. However then you need to have `<?XML encoding="Windows-1252"`.
2. For every gotten String the repair is:

   ```
    s = new String(s.getBytes("Cp1252"), StandardCharsets.UTF8);
   ```

If that is too cumbersome, translate the numeric entities `&#...;` to their byte value. And read the file content as UTF-8. Again the file must first be read as Windows-1252. Apache has some StringEscapeUtils.

---

### I came up with following code

```
String s = "<text>Weâ&#128;&#153;re ð&#159;&#146;¯ going to win</text>";
try {
    byte[] b = s.getBytes("Cp1252");
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; ++i) {
        byte bi = b[i];
        if (i < b.length - 4 && b[i] == '&' ) {
            if (b[i + 1] == '#' && Character.isDigit(b[i + 2])) {
                int j = i + 3;
                int cp = b[i + 2] - 48;
                while (j < b.length && Character.isDigit(b[j])) {
                    cp = 10*cp + b[j] - 48;
                    ++j;
                }
                if (j < b.length && b[j] == ';') {
                    bi = (byte)cp;
                    i = j;
                }
            }
        }
        baos.write(bi);
    }
    String t = baos.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    System.out.println("S: " + s);
    System.out.println("T: " + t);
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

This code **works** here. Copied the StackOverflow UTF-8 representation to Linux (also UTF-8) and compiled with UTF-8.

```
<text>We’re  going to win</text>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up pulling that field out of the file as a byte array as the files are small, then examining it byte-by-byte and converting all the Windows-1252 code points and HTML entities to the correct UTF-8 byte values then creating a `String` from the resulting byte array and replacing the existing DOM text node with that.

It's not pretty or fast but it seems to work.